# framer motion crashes next js app with the following error: "SyntaxError: Named export 'useId' not found"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I get this error on my next js app and I don't even know why or where its coming from since the code that's throwing the error is not even written by me.

```
error - file:///Users/cheq/Desktop/cheqo/node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/use-presence.mjs:1
import { useContext, useId, useEffect } from 'react';
                     ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'useId' not found. The requested module 'react' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'react';
const { useContext, useId, useEffect } = pkg;
```

I get this error when I import anything from framer motion, here is my full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

function motionpage() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>motionpage</div>
      <motion.button whileHover={{ scale: 1.02 }} whileTap={{ scale: 0.98 }}>
        Button
      </motion.button>
    </>
  );
}

export default motionpage;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It was a pretty long time ago, but maybe you remember what was the solution? I am experiencing exactly the same problem with framer-motion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`useId` is a new hook introduced in React 18. Upgrade your react version and try again.

Comment: Did not solve the problem, react was already at version 18.2.0 and the error ocured, may be caused by something else.